# FTPClient download file Access is denied

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

I am trying to download a file from an FTP server using Apache commons 2.0.

The following code is giving this error: "Access is denied".

Getting files list properly but whenever the download section executes the mentioned error occurs.

```
public class FTP extends Thread{
    @Override

    public void run() {
        try {
            FTPClient client=new FTPClient();
            client.connect(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.100"),2221);
            System.out.println(client.getReplyCode());
            boolean status=client.login("francis", "francis");
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            System.out.println(status);                
            FTPFile[] files=client.listFiles();
            System.out.println("Printing files list :");    
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                System.out.println(files[i].getName());
                client.setFileTransferMode(BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                client.setFileType(BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];                   
                if(files[i].isFile()){
                    System.out.println("Downloading........");
                    InputStream 
                    ins=client.retrieveFileStream(files[i].getName());
                    OutputStream outstream=new 
                    FileOutputStream("c:/"+files[i].getName());
                    int n=0;

                    while(ins.read(buffer)!=-1){
                        n=ins.read(buffer);
                        outstream.write(buffer,0,n);
                    }                       
                    File downloaded=new File("c:/"+files[i].getName());

                    if(files[i].getSize()==downloaded.length()){
                        System.out.println("Download succesfull..");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error downloading file");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FTP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        FTP thread=new FTP();
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

getting the following error on console

```html
   
Printing files list :<br>
DCIM<br>
Download<br>
LGBackup<br>
Movies<br>
Music<br>
Pictures<br>
Podcasts<br>
SHAREit<br>
Snapchat<br><br>
WhatsApp<br>
MobileTmoney.txt<br>
Downloading........<br>
Mar 27, 2018 12:41:17 PM ftp.FTP run<br>
SEVERE: null<br>
java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\MobileTmoney.txt (Access is denied)<br>
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.op<br>en0(Native Method)<br>
 at ftp.FTP.run(FTP.java:49)<br>
```

Comment: are you sure the credentials are correct and setup correctly on the server ?

Comment: Yes credentials are correct even giving the files lists with these credentials  out put is  as follows                                                                                   Printing files list :
Download
Foxit
LG PC Suite
LGBackup
Movies
Music
Notifications
Pictures
Podcasts
Quickset Setup
Ringtones
SHAREit
MobileTmoney.txt
Downloading........
Mar 27, 2018 12:41:17 PM ftp.FTP run
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\MobileTmoney.txt (Access is denied)

Comment: Include the stacktrace and the actual error (complete and literal, not paraphrased)

Comment: That error looks more like you can't write the file to the local path you are trying to or possibly when you read it after it has been written. A stack trace telling you on which exact line the exception occurs would help.

Comment: Exactly, your problem has obviously nothing to do with `FTPClient` nor file download.

Answer (score 1):

OS don't allow write your process in the disk. Your problem isn't FTP Client, is in `FileOutputStream`, make you sure that you have correct permissions to write.

Answer (score 0):

```
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

this line should be before login, after connect.